# What is CALM principle in Distributed systems?

Tags: distributed-system, consistency, eventual-consistency

Can you please site a working example of Consistency As Logical Monotonicity (CALM) ? I know the theory behind this but need to see a working example . 
Google searches redirect me to  technical research papers .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Bloom project](http://bloom-lang.net/index.html), they have some examples